# Look for an string inside a webpage without saving it in a file?

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

I'm new with Python and I have some questions!!

```
def extractdownloadurl(url):

    uresponse = urllib2.urlopen(url) #open url
    contents = uresponse.readlines() #readlines from url file
    fo = open("test.html","w") #open test.html
    for line in contents: 
        fo.write(line)#write lines from url file to text file
    fo.close()#close text file

    cadena = os.system('more test.html | grep uploads | grep zip >> cadena.html')

    f = open("cadena.html","r")
    text = f.read()
    f.close()


    match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', text)
    if match:
        cadena=match.group(0)


    texto = cadena[6:]


    os.system('rm test.html')
    os.system('rm cadena.html')
    return texto
```

This is my function to download a webpage and take one url following some conditions. It works. But I want to apply a more efficient way than saving the web on a file. I want to make something similar to a grep without save and read files (It's really slow). And other faster way of copy the url to a string.

Please write the code to look for a url inside contents without saving contents into a file.

I know that there are a lot of questions but I would be very grateful if you answer all of then.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you forward. This script prints all links from the web-page using your regular expression:

```
import re, urllib
page = urllib.urlopen("http://sebsauvage.net/index.html").read()
urls = re.findall('href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)',page)
for url in urls:
    print url
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Lycha's answer for python3

```
import re, urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://sebsauvage.net/index.html").read().decode('utf-8')
urls = re.findall('href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', page)
for url in urls:
    print(url)
```